# Changing configuration's maxBooleanClauses has no effect

Tags: solr

I'm upgrading from an old SOLR into SOLR 6. Installed version 6 on my local computer and started playing around to see how our old system copes with the new SOLR.

I have an old system that sometimes uses a lot of boolean clauses within a query. Yes, it would be best to upgrade it to query differently, but this is not doable currently.

I'm supposed to be able to change the maximum amount of boolean clauses via the `maxBooleanClauses` attribute in solrconfig.xml , but changing it has no effect. I set the same value (102400) to all (2) of my cores. The exception still says `Caused by: org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024`.

What I've tried:

- Reload all cores
- Unload all cores, and reload with `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=Companies&instanceDir=C:\temp\solr\solr-6.0.0\server\solr\Companies`
- Unload all cores and reload only one

Browsing the admin UI to Core Selector -> name -> Files -> solrconfig.xml shows the right value (102400).

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

Comment: Does this include solr restart...?

Comment: Change the value to 4096...and restart the server

Comment: Odd. Restarting did the thing. Hadn't thought of that, thanks :) Please add it as an answer.

Comment: Note that you have to reload ALL cores (even the previously existing ones) or modify their `solrconfig.xml` files manually. Only then is restarting the service guaranteed to have an effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the changes to solrConfig.xml restart the solr server. This will reflect the changes for you.

Comment: why does it need a restart ? why does reloading the core not work?

Comment: @gaurav5430 : Its the xml conf file and changes are not reflected until you restart.... I have not tried tried with reloading the core... Buy I think that will also not work as the core will refer a specific config set ...and config set has these files named solrConfig.xml...

Answer (score 0):

In Solr 9 you need to change also the value globally, for this please open your `solr.xml` file and change the entry `<int name="maxBooleanClauses">${solr.max.booleanClauses:1024}</int> to <int name="maxBooleanClauses">50000</int>`, optionally you can also add the line `SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.max.booleanClauses=50000` to the `/etc/default/solr.in.sh` file

> Replace 50000 for any value you want and ensure this value is also at the core `solrconfig.xml` configuration but be careful to use to big values, since Solr performance can collapse with too many boolean clauses.